# Compare two alphanumerical strings in ABAP

Tags: abap, alphanumeric

How can I compare two alphanumerical strings in ABAP?

Lets say I have two variables containing 5 characters:

```
DATA: lv_variable1 TYPE string VALUE '01234',
      lv_varoable2 TYPE string VALUE 'AB123'.
```

Now I want to know how I could check if lv_variable2 is "bigger" than lv_variable1. Can I just use the "GT" aka ">" operator?

Comment: Did you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenlogexp_character.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENLOGEXP_CHARACTER_2

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai That is the answer. Why don't you post it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA: lv_variable1 TYPE string VALUE '01234',
      lv_variable2 TYPE string VALUE 'AB123'.

IF lv_variable1 > lv_variable2.
  WRITE: / '1'.
ELSEIF lv_variable1 < lv_variable2. 
  WRITE: / '2'. "returned value
ELSE.
  WRITE: / 'meh'.
ENDIF.
```

This will work and as marked, it will print '2'.